# how to display map data in angular 2 typescript template

Tags: angular, typescript, dictionary

below is map in console.log;   :: 2,3  are key and respective game are values

```
 Map(0) {}  size :  (...) __proto__   :  Map [[Entries]]:Array(2)0:{2 => 
 "A"}1:{3 => B"}length:2
```

map is made by following::

```
 this.mapcustum= new Map<number, String>();
```

how to display map data without itretating in angular2

Comment: Where do you want to display ? Template Side ? How Do you want to display?

Comment: @VivekDoshi in angular template .html in table format

Comment: And you want to display them without looping ? how would you do it if it was simple array and not map , will you please explain ?